# How to resolve the problem that vscode no output when click run bottom?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have encountered a problem when running script in vscode. Previously, when I click rum bottom on the right top, it shows:

```
& D:/Software/Anaconda3/envs/pytorch-gpu/python.exe "d:/Research/hyperspectral classification/classification/aa.py"
```

in the terminal and runs correctly. But recently, when I run the script, it shows:

```
& conda run -n pytorch-gpu --no-capture-output --live-stream python "d:/Research/hyperspectral classification/classification/aa.py"
```

and the terminal doesn't show the results.

How can I change to previous command when I click run bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague of mine encountered the same problem today. We managed to solve it by downgrading the python extension in vscode.

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> to open extensions in vscode.
2. Select Python extension
3. Click dropdown menu next to Uninstall and Install Another Version
4. We selected the last version of 2021.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The anaconda you later installed caused the Python interpreter vscode was looking for to be inconsistent.
You can type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type "select Interpreter" and then choose the appropriate interpreter.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have change my interpreter, it seems not this reason. This is caused by the python extension version, and the upper answer can solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an easy solution; i once tried it on my c++ code as a beginner; I hope it helps. Close vscode, go to properties>compatibitlity, and disable the win eight checkbox; then reopen and run!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).